# /users/{id}/tags - 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: bug

this url is technically valid but generates 504.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/242897/tags?filter=c%23&fromdate=0&max=1577836800&min=0&page=1&pagesize=100&sort=Activity&todate=1577836800&key=qgAq_KfDu0KYzlNG-qaTuw